# Access Right for allocating new IP ranges in a hostproject inside Google Cloud

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, vpc

I have created a new Cloud SQL instance created and for the connectivity I want to assign it a prive IP from a different host project. Once I assign the corresponsing host network (Automatic IP) I get the following error:

```
Could not allocate new IP range because you do not have the required permissions on the host project.
```

I have the `Compute Network User` and the `Service Networking Admin` Role assigend to my user in the host network - does anybody know which additional right I need to allocate the IP address for my instance?

Comment: Can you please  confirm you are following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-ip#prerequisites) and your user has `compute.networkAdmin` role in host project?

Comment: The `compute.networkAdmin` Right was indeed missing - thanks for your help. If you can add it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am glad that I could help:

I would suggest you to follow the [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-ip#prerequisites) and ensure the user has `compute.networkAdmin` role in the host project.